# Unable to find the LCS cluster entry token file

Tags: liferay

I just installed Liferay standalone on my local development laptop and started it.
PROBLEM: The log prints this every minute:

```
07:01:36,157 INFO  [Thread-33][LCSClusterEntryTokenAdvisor:238] Unable to find the LCS cluster entry token file
07:01:36,167 INFO  [Thread-33][LCSConnectorRunnable:73] Unable to get LCS cluster entry token
07:01:36,167 INFO  [Thread-33][LCSConnectorRunnable:111] LCS portlet is not connected
07:01:36,167 INFO  [Thread-33][LCSConnectorRunnable:127] Retry in 60 seconds
```

It is very annoying. How to fix the root problem, or otherwise prevent this from getting printed?

My exact version is 7.0.10 GA1 (EE DXP 7.0 SP3 fix pack 15-7010).
The only "configuration" I did was to tell the wizard to use MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on non-production environment go to bundles\osgi\marketplace and just **delete** the **Liferay Connected Services Client.lpkg**. Hope this helps.

Comment: I upvoted too early haha... While the LCS log lines do not appear anymore, it is because Liferay does not start anymore: `NullPointerException at DirectServletRegistryUtil.clearServlets` ([full log](https://gist.github.com/nicolas-raoul/a978cf9968845e7cfe42ea72ee1a2766)). After I put back a backup of the file, Liferay starts successfully again.

Comment: Have you cleared the OSGi state & portal work folder (outside one) ? I don't see a reason for `NullPointerException at DirectServletRegistryUtil.clearServlets()` as this is just a map clearing and the map is already initialized `private final Map<String, ServletInfo> _servletInfos =
  new ConcurrentHashMap<>();` > I guess you should clear the cached data and state of the portal server.

Answer (score -1):

There was an issue with lcs connections that seems to have been fixed by now.

If the message is still appearing, you could also check if there is an updated version of the lcs portlet available or just change the log settings as a last resort. Or, as it's the enterprise version, just open a support ticket.